# Do Spring.NET and Common.Logging XML schemas (XSD) exist?

Tags: .net, xsd, spring.net, common.logging

[Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) 1.2.0 M1 comes with several XSD files for the <objects> node, database stuff, etc.  However, it is an incomplete collection because it does not seem to include <spring> (used in `App.config`), <context>, or <parsers> elements.  Additionally, [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) doesn't appear to have *any* XSD's included in the source or distribution.

We'd like to have these so that Visual Studio won't complain about them on compile time when it validates the `App.config`.  It's nice having the schemas in place, because of the compile-time check which helps you find XML bugs *before* your program throws up in Spring.

Do these exist anywhere / are in development or, alternatively, has anyone written some themselves?

On the same token, has anyone seen/resolved the following message?

> Could not find schema information for the attribute
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Intellisense:friendlyname'
>   (spring-objects-1.1.xsd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't exist for  or  or the other top level elements that are used in App.config.  Please enter a JIRA issue for Spring [here](http://jira.springframework.org/secure/BrowseProject.jspa?id=10020) as well as for Common Logging - [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=182424&atid=901159).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the XSD tool to reverse engineer an XML output file into the XSD you need? I did something similar when writing my own tool for log4net to get an XSD file.

Comment: What Xsd tool would that be?

Comment: Hmm... there's a question for that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000905/best-xsd-file-generator