# Best XSD file generator

Tags: xml, xsd

I am analyzing tools that generate XSD file from XML files. I find lot of tools in internet.

1. XSD.exe utility that comes along with Visual Studio (xsd file.xml)
2. Stylus Studio's XSD file generator
3. XSD Interference tool from Microsoft
4. XMLFox Professional
5. Liquid XML Studio (XML Editor reverse engineering)

Which of the above is best if cost-price is not a criteria ? 
If any other tool is better than the tools listed above, lemme know.

Are there any free tool for XSD file generation from XML file ? 
I searched and got this link http://www.hitsw.com/xml_utilites/ , But this supports only DTD and not XML Schema.  Which could be best freeware for XSD file generation from XML file ? Any ideas ?

Thx in advans,
Karthik Balaguru

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using a licensed version of Liquid XML Studio, and I'm quite pleased with it. It works well, seems like "overwhelming" in features than others, and so far, I have no yet found anything that I cannot do in Liquid XML Studio. Liquid XML Studio is also available as a free community edition with slightly reduced feature set (not sure if those limitations would affect the XML schema stuff...)

Their support is very responsive and so far has been able to resolve any of my issues. I can definitely recommend Liquid XML Studio.

I also use the `xsd.exe` tool at times - works quite nicely for simple scenarios, and it's always at my fingertips (since I'm a command-line junkie and always have a few command windows open). xsd.exe is definitely "free" (as in: it comes with Visual Studio - no extra purchase).

Comment: Okay,I am also looking for the same kind of tool in linux .
Is there any free tool in linux environment ? 

Thx in advans, Karthik Balaguru

Answer (score 1):

[XMLSpy](http://www.xmlspy.com) has a 30 day trial and can do many fabulous things with/for XML.  I've been using it since about 2005 for my XML needs

Comment: Is XMLSpy superior to Liquid XML Studio ?

Thx in advans,
Karthik Balaguru

Comment: I couldn't say, having never used liquid XML.

I can say that XMLSpy is easy to use.  It supports tag/attribute completion, learns as you type, generates schemas/xsds from xml, generates xml from schemas, and has a most excellent xpath and xsl debugger (lets you step through the xsl and inspect values, etc) .  It has integration with visual studio as well.  Also, the website talks about how it runs well under WINE for *nix systems, if that interests you